# How to remove * at the end of each protein sequence in a fasta file

Tags: text-processing, bioinformatics

I have a fasta file containing multiple sequences (amino acid sequences) of a particular protein. The last character of the sequences are denoted as "*", which actually represents the stop codon. I am trying to do a multiple sequence alignment using MUSCLE but the tool rejects all sequences with "*" at the end.

How do I remove the "*" ?

For example my input file is:

```
>seq1
MSDGFHS*
>Seq2
MSDRFH*
```

What I need is:

```
>seq1
MSDGFHS
>Seq2
MSDRFH
```

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange.  What have you tried?  Please [edit] your question and tell us where you are stuck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `sed`.  For example:

```
$ printf ">seq1\nMSDGFHS*\n>Seq2\nMSDRFH*\n" | sed -e 's/\*$//'
>seq1
MSDGFHS
>Seq2
MSDRFH
```

This removes any literal asterisk character (`*`) at the end of a line.

You can use sed's `-i` option to edit the original file(s) in place.   Or just redirect `sed`'s output to a new fasta file and use that as input to MUSCLE, which would be a better option if you also needed to use the original file with other programs (it's generally better to *not* delete information permanently - once you delete data, there's no guarantee you can ever get it back.  Backups are always good, as is using temporary modified versions of files for special purposes).

Answer (score 2):

If your data doesn't contain `*`s in other positions that you want to keep then this is a job that `tr` exists to do:

```
$ tr -d '*' < file
>seq1
MSDGFHS
>Seq2
MSDRFH
```

Answer (score 1):

`vi` works:

```
vi file.txt
:1,$s/\*$//
ZZ
```

This tells `vi` to address all lines in the file (`1,$`) and whenever a literal `*` (which is escaped because it is a regex meta-character) is found at the end of a line (`$`), it is replaced with nothing, i.e. it is deleted.

As `@roaima` pointed out in a now-deleted comment, the search-and-replace command can be written somewhat more conveniently as:

```
:%s/\*//
```

Comment: Thank you, @roaima. I've been using a large repeat factor for years, so my `9` key will thank you also.

Answer (score 0):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

```perl
raku -pe 's/ \* $ //;'
```

Sample Input:

```
>seq1
MSDGFHS*
>Seq2
MSDRFH*
```

Sample Output:

```
>seq1
MSDGFHS
>Seq2
MSDRFH
```

By this time you should be familiar with the `s///` "[triple-solidus](https://docs.raku.org/syntax/s$SOLIDUS$SOLIDUS$SOLIDUS)" idiom. Above is the idiom performed in Raku, a member of the Perl family of programming languages. The `-e` flag tells Raku to expect a 'one-liner' program (and not, for example, the name of a script file), with `strict` enabled by default. The `-p` flag runs the code linewise autoprinting the `$_` topic variable at the end of each line.

Between the two left solidus characters the regex searches for a `\*` (backslash-escaped) literal asterisk, followed by the `$` end-of-string zero-width assertion. Between the two right solidus characters is nothing, so any end-of-line asterisks are replaced with nothing (i.e. deleted).

In an interesting twist, you can switch to Raku's `-ne` non-autoprinting linewise flag(s), and the `s///` idiom will return line-by-line what you've picked out for modification/deletion (presuming you've appended a print statement like `say`):

```perl
raku -ne 's/ \* $ //.say;'  test.fasta
Nil
｢*｣
Nil
｢*｣
```

Finally, if you don't have a strong preference regarding Bioinformatic toolkits, you might consider either [BioPerl](https://bioperl.org/) or [BioPerl6](https://github.com/cjfields/bioperl6/).

https://raku.org